# How to make a custom button that will take urls from redux state and navigate back taking those urls like history.goBack method would?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, navigation

The problem: I have an explicit assignment to make a custom button that does not use browsers native go back button and instead I need to make one inside a component and store browsed urls to redux state and use those stored urls for a button that onClick will go back just like history.goBack would but in this case this method is not an option. I've managed only to store the urls to state and onClick to remove the last browsed url from state.

here are some Component snippets:

```
const PageComponent = props => {

    useEffect(() => {
        props.addUrl(props.history.location.pathname);
    }, [props.history.location.pathname]);

    return (
        <main>
            <div className="page">
                <div>
                    <h1>{props.history.location.pathname.split("/").pop().replace('-', ' ')}</h1>
                    <div className="underline bg-black"></div>
                </div>
                <button onClick={() => {
                    props.removeUrl();
                }}>BACK</button>

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    addUrl: url => dispatch({ type: 'ADD_URL', payload: url }),
    removeUrl: () => dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_URL' })
});
```

Reducer:

```
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_URL':
            return {
                ...state,
                pages: state.pages.concat(action.payload)
            }
        case 'REMOVE_URL':
            const updatedUrls = state.pages.slice(0, -1)
            return {
                ...state,
                pages: updatedUrls
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    };
};
```